# How to integrate this $\int \left[(u+a)(u+b)\right]^{n-1} du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I having some problems with the following integral

$$\int \left[(u+a)(u+b)\right]^{n-1} du$$

I try to use $u$-substituion and integration by parts but is not working. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Write $(u+a)(u+b)=x^2-c^2$ with $x:=u+\tfrac{a+b}{2},\,c:=\frac{a-b}{2}$ so for $n\ge1$ your integral is$$\begin{align}\int(x^2-c^2)^{n-1}dx&=\int\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}(-c^2)^{n-1-k}x^{2k}dx\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}(-c^2)^{n-1-k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+C\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\left(-\left(\tfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\right)^{n-1-k}\frac{(u+\tfrac{a+b}{2})^{2k+1}}{2k+1}+C\end{align}$$by the binomial theorem.

Comment: How does the binomial theorem works for this integration?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval See edit.

Comment: Does this apply when is n-1 because you are using just n?

Comment: @AlexisSandoval Sorry, fixed.

Comment: provided that $|x/c|<1$

Comment: @GCab That constraint is only needed if $n$ isn't a positive integer.

Comment: right, sorry, here the sum is limited